# how to hide files in the www directory

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Is it possible to hide a folder from the www directory so that the php files will not be seen if you access it through a web browser?
I'm doing this because I'm not yet good enough to secure those files and the mysql database that they are manipulating. 
Or even a trick that would make the web browser not to be able to access the localhost is fine. Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple trick if you don't have Apache, hence no access to .htaccess (that sounds like I'm repeating myself), just create a file index.htm or index.html containing NOTHING. Any attempt to access that folder will just show a blank page.

Comment: yeah thanks, Im not really using my brain at all at times, thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

If you have a directory and you don't want Apache being able to serve any file that's in it, you can create a `.htaccess` file in that directory, containing :

```
Deny from all
```

This will make sure Apache refuses serving any file from that directory -- but they will still be accessible by PHP scripts running from another directory or from the command-line.

If you want Apache to be able to serve the files, but not list the content of the directory when a user accesses that directory without any filename in the URL, you can use this in your `.htaccess` file :

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will disable listing of files inside the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file -- but will not prevent Apache from serving the files themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Just put the files outside of the document root and include them from there.

Comment: I don't think this would be the solution, I forgot to tell that I am accessing this files using a vb.net program through the web browser function

Comment: You seem to have mistakenly tagged this question "php" then.